# Error in `sym()`: using wbm() function from the package 'panelr'

Tags: regression, panel, between, hybrid, sym

I have a panel dataset with 289 local governments and 3 years. One of my explanatory variables, 'manco', is a time-invariant variable, so I'm forced to use an alternative method to fixed effects, in this case i chose the within-between model, also known as hybrid model.

I'm using the function wbm() from the package panelr. This is my model:

```
wb2 <- wbm(efic ~  faf + mun_tur + disper + envell + distancia + priv | manco, data = datos9)
```

However, when i run the model i get this error:

```
Error in `sym()`:
! Can't convert `NULL` to a symbol.
Backtrace:
 1. panelr::wbm(...)
 2. panelr:::wb_prepare_data(...)
 7. rlang::sym(id)
```

Just wanna know how to solve it so i can run it. The code is just like this one from an introduction example to the package 'panelr' available in this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/panelr/vignettes/wbm.html